# Custom lists conversion to html

Tags: tex4ht, html

I have managed to produce a latex file that works perfectly and I would like the same functionality using tex4ht on the same file.

Basically, I have several custom `\item` label that I use to provide custom formatting for both bullet icon and the content following regardless of the level at which they are placed. If it is a numbered list, the number will be dependant upon the level but not the formatting. The following code detects whether or not the environment is `itemize` or `enumerate`. Then it provides the appropriate formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \items This is items
        \itemi This is itemi
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \items This is items
        \itemi This is itemi
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In my preamble, I have the following:

```
\makeatletter
   \def\specialenvironment{itemize}
   \def\formatitems{\color{Black}\,}
   \def\items{%
       \ifx\@currenvir\specialenvironment
          \item[\normalfont{}{\color{Black}\textbullet}]
       \else 
          \expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
          \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
          \expandafter\formatitems\originallabel}%
          \item
          \expandafter\let\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname\originallabel 
    \fi
\color{Black}
}
\def\formatitemi{\color{OliveGreen}\,}
\def\itemi{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\specialenvironment
        \item[\normalfont{}{\color{OliveGreen}\textit{{i}}}]
    \else 
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
        \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\formatitemi\originallabel}%
        \item
        \expandafter\let\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname\originallabel   
    \fi
\color{OliveGreen}
}
\makeatother
```

This runs without error in tex4ht but does not provide the appropriate formatting. I have tried using the `\ConfigureEnv`, `\ConfigureList` and `\NewConfigure` commands in my tex4ht config file but without any success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you want to customize item labels and color. By default, `tex4ht` removes itemize and enumerate labels and uses `CSS` to display them, we can use `\ConfigureList` to fix that, together with some `CSS` to suppress labels added by the browser. We can also use `\ConfigureList` to add `class` attributes on `li` elements, so we can assign colors for them.

First of all, move definitions of your macros to standalone package, `items.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{items}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{rgb}{0.3,0.4,0.2}
   \def\specialenvironment{itemize}
   \def\formatitems{\color{Black}\,}
   \def\items{%
       \ifx\@currenvir\specialenvironment
          \item[\normalfont{}{\color{Black}\textbullet}]
       \else 
          \expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
          \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
          \expandafter\formatitems\originallabel}%
          \item
          \expandafter\let\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname\originallabel 
    \fi
\color{Black}
}
\def\formatitemi{\color{OliveGreen}\,}
\def\itemi{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\specialenvironment
        \item[\normalfont{}{\color{OliveGreen}\textit{{i}}}]
    \else 
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
        \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\formatitemi\originallabel}%
        \item
        \expandafter\let\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname\originallabel   
    \fi
\color{OliveGreen}
}
\endinput
```

and configuration file for `tex4ht`, `items.4ht`:

```
\def\ItemsType{items}
\newcommand\ConfigureMyList[2]{%
\ConfigureList{#1}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<#2 class="#1">\Hnewline}\ShowPar%
    \bgroup 
    \def\EndDefItem{}
   }
   {\EndDefItem\egroup%
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</#2>\Hnewline}\ShowPar%
    \par}{\EndDefItem\HCode{<li class="\ItemsType" >}\def\EndDefItem{\HCode{</li>\Hnewline}}}{}
}


\ConfigureMyList{itemize}{ul}
\ConfigureMyList{enumerate}{ol}

\newcommand\ConfigureMyItems[2]{%
\pend:def#1{\def\ItemsType{#2}}%
}

\ConfigureMyItems\items{items}
\ConfigureMyItems\itemi{itemi}

\Css{ul, ol{list-style-type: none;}}

\newcommand\tsf@getColor[1][.]{       
  % colorname `.` holds current color 
  \extractcolorspec{#1} {\tsf@color} 
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf@color{HTML}\tsf@color
}

\newcommand\MyItemColor[2]{%
  \tsf@getColor[#2]%
  \Css{.#1{color:\#\tsf@color;}}
}

\MyItemColor{items}{Black}
\MyItemColor{itemi}{OliveGreen}
```

we've defined some commands, in order to simplify the configuration. With `\ConfigureMyList`, you configure an environment `#1` to use 
list element `#2`. Environments supported by default are:

```
\ConfigureMyList{itemize}{ul}
\ConfigureMyList{enumerate}{ol}
```

you can add any other list environment,

interesting part of our `\ConfigureList` is:

```
{\EndDefItem\HCode{<li class="\ItemsType" >}\def\EndDefItem{\HCode{</li>\Hnewline}}}
```

`ItemsType` must be defined in `\items` and `\itemi` and it must expand to the class name, which will be used to assign the color. Also note that default configurations for enumerate and itemize use `\DeleteMark` at the end of third parameter for `\ConfigureList`, so LaTeX label is deleted and `CSS` is used instead to generate the label.

Css generated labels are disabled with:

```
\Css{ul, ol{list-style-type: none;}}
```

We  need to insert definition of `\ItemsType` to our custom `\item` macros. To simplify the process, we can create a helper macro:

```
\newcommand\ConfigureMyItems[2]{%
\pend:def#1{\def\ItemsType{#2}}%
}
```

the `\ConfigureMyItems` command will insert the definition at the beginning of the redefined command:

```
\ConfigureMyItems\items{items}
\ConfigureMyItems\itemi{itemi}
```

`class` names are now accessible from our list configuration. We have only to declare colors used for the classes:

```
\MyItemColor{items}{Black}
\MyItemColor{itemi}{OliveGreen}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Just for the record, this works perfectly and has solved my problem. Thank you so much.